# Connecting VBA to SQL server using ADO - object closed

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I have created the object and from which I can tell I have just preformed a query on it, can anyone tell me where my error is?

The error statement is

```
“Run time error ‘3704’ operation is not allowed when the object is closed”
```

and it occurs on this line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rspubs
```

MY CODE IS

```
Sub sqlTest()

Dim Sqlquery As String
Dim cnpubs As ADODB.Connection
Dim rspubs As ADODB.Recordset

' Create a connection object.
Set cnpubs = New ADODB.Connection
' Create a recordset object.
Set rspubs = New ADODB.Recordset
' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String


'Construct query
Sqlquery = " sql query;”

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=XXXX;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=XXXX;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Prospects" 

'Now open the connection.
cnpubs.Open strConn

With rspubs
' Assign the Connection object.
.ActiveConnection = cnpubs
' Extract the required records.
'.Source = Sqlquery
.Open Sqlquery
' Copy the records into cell A1 on Required Sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SQL").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rspubs
End With

' Tidy Up
cnpubs.Close
rspubs.Close

Set cnpubs = Nothing

Set rspubs = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the query you want to run.  All you have for Sqlquery is " sql query;”  which does not return a recordset.  Try changing the string to `Select 1 as testvalue` to test something.

Comment: I'm assuming that text is just filler for the sake of posting online and they actually have some real SQL in there. But the idea is still valid. Is your query in fact valid?

Comment: @Brad Good Point!  To the OP, you may need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` also on the top of your query.  It will suppress the messages that say (x row(s) affected) from the SQL Server.